# Bottom Border to specific section

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a DIV an inside it is a H1 tag with some description , I'm able to give a border-bottom to the whole H1 tag but how to give a border-bottom to just a particular part of it like in the snippet below.

[image: It should come like this]

Adding a SPAN tag works, but after giving padding to the border to add space it spreads wrongly breaking the text format.

HTML :

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="column1">
        <h3 class="">
        <span>Responsive  Web Design </span>
        </h3>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>
            Coupling aesthetic design sensibilities with.
        </p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#column1 > h3 > span{
border-bottom: 5px solid #16a085;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used :pseudo elemnt to add a border to the element

```css
/** = for better view not required */

.row {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/** = end */
span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px; /* change as per your design */
  height: 2px; /* change as per your design */
  background: blue; /* change as per your design */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="column1">
    <h3 class="">
        <span>Responsive  Web Design </span>
        </h3>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>
      Coupling aesthetic design sensibilities with.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks !!, but the pseudo element is not taking the change.

Comment: can you create a fiddle or demo and show me @user3211681

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxRZWN?editors=1100] check this you will need to remove border and add background color for the pseudo element

Comment: your welcome @user3211681 do accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<span>` and the `<br>` tags and style the `<h1>` using css to create the spacing above and below the heading.  Then add a pseudo element for the line.

The example I'm showing below uses `position: absolute` on the pseudo element.  To ensure that it positions properly make sure the h1 style has `position: relative`.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  padding: 120px 0 25px;
}
h1::before { /* for the graphic */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: transparent url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/communication-3/512/computer_phone_tablet-512.png) left top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
h1::after { /* for the line below the h1 */
   content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Web Design</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sed umini.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sed umini.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the advise my code looks more polished now :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm suggesting you to go for the first answer. But if you find this `pseudo` thing bit confusing, then try the [**`<hr>`**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) tag. Give it a fixed width and place it below the title. Simple and clean.

See **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2bzoc1ac/)**

```css
#column1 > h3 > span{
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.text-center hr{
  border-bottom: 5px solid #16a085;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="column1">
        <h3 class="">
        <span>Responsive  Web Design </span>
        </h3>
        <hr/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>
            Coupling aesthetic design sensibilities with.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `display` property to `inline-block` like so
`display: inline-block;`
and then it will work